# Crawl menu (according to hierarchy) with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The goal is crawl an e-commerce menu and return all categories respecting taxonomy levels (N1, N2 and N3). I´m getting good results but N3 categories are shown last and separately on the output json.

Example:
N1 --> N2, N1 --> N2, N1 --> N2, N1 --> N2,
N3, N3, N3, N3

I want to get the categories with all the three specific levels. Each N1 with their N2 and each N2 with their N3.

So the structure I need is:

**N1-N2-N3 (N1 category Muebles)

N1-N2-N3 (N1 category Herramientas)

N1-N2-N3 (N1 category Automovil)

...**

My code:

```
import urlparse
import scrapy


class ReadySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'cats2'
start_urls = ['http://www.sodimac.com.ar']

def parse(self, response):
    # loop over all cover  N1 links elements on main menu
    SELECTOR = '//*[@id="navBarLeave"]/ul/li/a/@href'
    for href in response.xpath(SELECTOR).extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href), self.parse_n2)

    # loop over all N2 on left menu
def parse_n2(self, response):
    SELECTOR = '.jq-accordionGroup'
    for ready in response.css(SELECTOR):
        N1 = 'menu.menu-list h1::text'
        N2 = '//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/text()'
        Linkn2 = '//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/@href'
        
        # come back with results
        yield {
        'N1': response.css(N1).extract(),
        'N2': response.xpath(N2).extract(),
        'Linkn2': response.xpath(Linkn2).extract(),
        }

        for href in response.xpath(Linkn2).extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href), self.parse_n3)

    # loop over all N3 on left menu
def parse_n3(self, response):
    SELECTOR = '.jq-accordionGroup'
    for ready in response.css(SELECTOR).extract():
        N3 = '//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/text()'
        Linkn3 = '//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/@href'

    # come back with results
        yield {
        'N3': response.xpath(N3).extract(),
        'Linkn3': response.xpath(Linkn3).extract(),
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `Item` like so

```
class CustomItem(scrapy.Item):
    N1 = scrapy.Field()
    N2 = scrapy.Field()
    N3 = scrapy.Field()
```

and pass this item along your `requests` with the `meta` attribute.

```
def parse_n1(self, response):
    item = CustomItem()
    item['N1'] = ...

    request = scrapy.Request(..., callback=self.parse_n2)
    request.meta['item'] = item   # attach to request
    yield request

def parse_n2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']  # <- unpack from response
    item['N2'] = ...              # <- fill more fields
    yield item                    # <- finally pass the item to output
```

This is pseudo code. Please adapt to your need.

Comment: Thanks @Frank! Sorry but don´t know how to apply this to my estrcuture. I have to reach to level N3

Comment: You can add more levels by adding a request to parse_n and pass the item further to parse_n+1. Add so many levels you need.

Comment: in this way I could download with format N1-N2-Linkn2-N3-Linkn3 (N1 category Muebles) / N1-N2-Linkn2-N3-Linkn3 (N1 category Herramientas) / N1-N2-Linkn2-N3-Linkn3 (N1 category Automovil) / .....  ?

I need each N3 atacched to each N2

Comment: Yes - By collecting the level infos into items the information is attached together. Give it a try!

Comment: I try based in yor suggestion but I´m getting stuck when I add the third level. I paste it below!

Answer (score 1):

```
import urlparse
import scrapy
from ready.items import ReadyItem

class ReadySpider(scrapy.Spider):   
name = 'cats3'
start_urls = ['http://www.sodimac.com.ar']

def parse(self, response):
    # loop over all cover  N1 links elements on main menu
    SELECTOR = '//*[@id="navBarLeave"]/ul/li/a/@href'
    for href in response.xpath(SELECTOR).extract():
        item = ReadyItem()

        request = scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href), self.parse_n2)
        request.meta['item'] = item   # attach to request
        yield request


    # loop over all N2 on left menu
def parse_n2(self, response):
    SELECTOR = '.jq-accordionGroup'
    for ready in response.css(SELECTOR):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['NameN1'] = response.css('menu.menu-list h1::text').extract()
        item['NameN2'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['LinkN2'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/@href').extract()
        yield request

        request = scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href), self.parse_n3)
        request.meta['item'] = item   # attach to request
        yield request

def parse_n3(self, response):
    SELECTOR = '.jq-accordionGroup'
    for ready in response.css(SELECTOR):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['NameN3'] = response.css('//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['LinkN3'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="jq-accordion"]/a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Looks not so bad but there are someone issues. 1. You don't need the item in the first parse block if there is no value to assign.  2. There are two "yield request" in parse_2. Remove the first. Other than that the logfile can be informative.

Comment: @FrankMartin now works nice! The only problem I have now is that item link n2 and link n3 are relative urls. With URL join I can't extract them because I get a list error. Only  I can using extract first but I need all the links with absolute url. Any suggestions? Thanks so much! You are the best

Comment: scrapys response object provides a `urljoin` method. So you should be able to write something like `link = response.urljoin(extracted_url)`. Consider to ask a new question if you encounter any problems.